# Difference between \u{1f642} and \u1f642 unicode representations in js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

`\u1f642` renders as `ὤ2` while `\u{1f642}` renders as

What is the difference between these two?

I expected both to render as

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-yalow-oflcbp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `\u1f642` === `\u{1f64}2` or `"\u1f64" + "2"` see [MDN Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences explains the difference: "\uXXXX …where XXXX is exactly 4 hex digits in the range 0000–FFFF;", and "\u{X}…\u{XXXXXX} …where X…XXXXXX is 1–6 hex digits in the range 0–10FFFF" With exactly four digits, there is no ambiguity - but with the other cases, the computer would have no way of telling, whether you meant `\u12345` to be `\u1234` followed by the _character_ `5`, or whether you meant the full `12345` to be the hexadecimal number.

Comment: [(JavaScript) ES6 Unicode code point escapes](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/#es6-unicode-code-point-escapes) ES6/ES2015 introduced a way to represent Unicode points in the astral planes (any Unicode code point requiring more than 4 chars), by wrapping the code in curly brackets: '\u{XXXXX}'.